# Sum of an Array & ArrayClass List

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

Here is the Die Class you asked for... Alex could you explain further about using .getValue in my Die Class?

---

```
public class Die
{
   private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value mutator.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void setFaceValue (int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value accessor.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
    }
}
```

I've tried using different code to find the sum of my Array and ArrayList... here is my code. Could someone please tell me how to solve the end.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int SIZE = 10;
        Die sumArray;
        Die sumArrayList;


        Die[] DieList = new Die[SIZE];

        ArrayList<Die> DieList2 = new ArrayList<Die>();

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            DieList[i] = new Die();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            DieList2.add(new Die());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            DieList[i].roll();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            DieList2.get(i).roll();
        }

        System.out.print("Array: "); 

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
        System.out.print(DieList[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("ArrayList: " + DieList2); //.get(index) specific index value in the arrayList

        for (Die i : sumArray){
            sumArray+= i;
        }

    //  sumArrayList = (DieList2(0) + DieList[1] + DieList[2] + DieList[3] + DieList[4] + DieList[5] + DieList[6] + DieList[7] + DieList[8] + DieList[9] + DieList[10]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Knowing the Die class would help.

Comment: Can i ask why you are using an ArrayList and an Array while doing the same thing with them both?

Comment: Consider collapsing the first 4 for loops into one loop with a four-statement body, much more condensed and readable...

Comment: Thanks for responding guys. Yeah, I'm in a introductory Java course, so my understanding of much of this is very limited.

Comment: @austinwernli the assignment I'm working on asks for both an Array and ArrayList to be used to store the face values of 10 randomly rolled Die each.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are missunderstanding some concepts:

- The print method defined in Object class (the class from which all classes inherit) will print the reference of the object, not any attribute. This should be obvious, as print method couldn't know which attribute to print (neither a list of attributes and references is stored in an object to go one by one). If you need to print its inner attributes, you need to write a method specifically to do so or overwrite the print method, but if you don't have a good reason to overwrite a predefined method don't do it. Call it getValue() i.e.
- sumArray is only an object, not a list of objects. The way you are iterating through the first for loop is reading only one object, as sumArray is one of your Die objects, not a list.
- Except for Strings, the operator + is used only for primitive types (int, boolean, float, ...). If the += is not breaking your compilation, I understand the compiler is interpreting the operation as a single assignment operation, hence you are saying that the reference sumArray now points again to... sumArray. The statement is useless.
- As for the last line commented, you CANNOT sum objects for the reasons explained above. An object is a complex entity compound by many attributes and methods and the compiler cannot know how to sum by default these entities. If by any reason you arrived to Java from C++ be awared that you cannot overload operators (but surely that's not your case)

So, if you want a solution

- Define a getValue() method in your Die class to read the value stored. I assume you have properly coded the roll value to generate a value and store it.

To sum all the values from your array do:

```
int sums1=0;    
for (Die i : DieList){
sums1+= i.getValue();
}
```

To sum all the values from your ArrayList do:

```
int sums2=0;    
for (int i=0;i<DieList2.size();i++){
     sums2+= DieList2.get(i).getValue();
}
```

And finally to print them:

```
System.out.println("Sum of array elements: "+sums1);
System.out.println("Sum of ArrayList elements: "+sums2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to find the sum of the array after rolling the dice you could shorten your code up a lot!

You can condense all adding, rolling, and summing of your dice in one loop like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 10;
    int sumList1 = 0;
    int sumList2 = 0;
    Die[] DieList = new Die[SIZE];
    ArrayList < Die > DieList2 = new ArrayList < Die > ();

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        DieList[i] = new Die();
        DieList2.add(new Die());
        DieList[i].roll();
        DieList2.get(i).roll();
        sumList1 += DieList[i].getFaceValue();
        sumList2 += DieList2.get(i).getFaceValue();
    }

    System.out.println("Sum of Array: " + sumList1);
    System.out.println("Sum of ArrayList: " + sumList2);
    System.out.println("Sum of both: " + (sumList1 + sumList2));
}
```